# Complexity of formulae involving projective sets in Polish spaces

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, descriptive-set-theory, descriptive-complexity

I am no expert in descriptive set theory, but for some reason want to estimate the complexity of a certain formula.

**The framework.** Let be $F$ a projective set in the Polish space $X=\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$, say it is [in the family $\mathbf \Pi^1_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_hierarchy). Then, for a fixed $x_0 \in X$ I consider the formula $\varphi$:

$$ x_0\cdot y \in F,$$

where multiplication is performed pointwise and $y$ is the free variable bounded by $X$.

**Question.** Is it possible to compute (or estimate) the [complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_descriptive_set_theory#Arithmetical_hierarchy) of $\varphi$ in terms of the projective complexity of $F$, that is, $n$?

This could well be obvious, however, it is not my area of expertise at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the term *arithmetic complexity* is not used for projective sets such as the one above, because in the arithmetic hierarchy one is concerned with first order formulas on the language of arithmetic: individual variables range over the natural numbers and you have $+$, $\cdot$, $0$ and $1$ as available operations; notably quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$ can only be used with those individual variables. But in order to define a projective set, you need variables that range over (possibly uncountable) Polish spaces. This is better understood on the space $2^{\mathbb{N}} \cong \mathop{\mathrm{Pow}}(\mathbb{N})$, but of course there are Borel isomorphisms between this and any other uncountable Polish space (and this will not change the result, if we start at $\boldsymbol\Pi^1_1$, $\boldsymbol\Sigma^1_1$, or above).

A finer detail is that in the hypothesis you refer to a boldface $\boldsymbol\Pi^1_n$ set. Those, apart from the (second order) formula, need a parameter to be defined.

Now, let's consider the complexity of 
$$
Y := \{ y \in X : x_0 \cdot y \in F\}.
$$

It is clear that if all components of $x_0$ are non null, then it will have exactly the same complexity as $F$ ($y\mapsto x_0\cdot y$ being a homeomorphism). As soon as some component is $0$, then $Y$ will be homeomorphic to a projection of $F$, and hence hence its complexity may grow to $\boldsymbol\Sigma^1_{n+1}$ (that is, one extra second order existential quantifier). Had we started with a $\boldsymbol\Sigma^1_n$ set, $Y$ would have been also $\boldsymbol\Sigma^1_n$.

Comment: Thanks, that's very instructive. Just let me ask you if I understand this right. Suppose that $F$ is a projective filter (regarded as a subset of $2^{\mathbb N}$). For a variable $y\in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ and $x_0\in \mathbb R$, I consider the formula $\lim_F y_n = x_0$. (This means, $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists A\in F \forall n\in A |y_n - x_0| < \varepsilon$. Is the complexity of the formula $\Pi^0_{n+2}$ if $F\in \mathbf \Pi^0_n$? That's because the set $A:=\{y\in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}: \forall_m \{n\in \mathbb N: |y_n - x_0| < 1/m\}\in F$ will increase it by 2?

Comment: Note that you are putting a $0$ superscript now; that would mean a Borel set. If we insist on $F\in \mathbf \Pi^1_n$, the set defined by that formula is a priori, indeed, $\boldsymbol\Pi^1_{n+2}$. But also note that you don't need all $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}$ to conclude, just those of the form $\frac{1}{n}$; and that's just a number quantifier. So using that, we are at $\boldsymbol\Sigma^1_{n+1}$ (because both pointclasses are closed under countable union and intersection).

Comment: (In case you really meant $0$ above, the definition would be just $\boldsymbol\Sigma^1_{1}$.)

Comment: Thanks, indeed, I meant $\mathbf \Pi^1_n$. So to make sure: I go from $\mathbf \Pi^1_n$ to $\mathbf \Sigma^1_{n+1}$ as I express the set whether the formula holds true by introducing one more universal quantifier? In such arguments, is it fine, or is it customary to write such sets as projections/complements of some products involving the original sets? This is more a question of what people working in the area consider standard.

Comment: You go from $\boldsymbol\Pi^1_{n}$ to $\boldsymbol\Sigma^1_{n+1}$ if you add another _existential_ quantifier (ranging over an uncountable Polish space) before the rest. (And from $\boldsymbol\Sigma^1_{n}$ to $\boldsymbol\Pi^1_{n+1}$ if you add a universal one.) In general, once you write out the definition it is clear enough what the complexity is. But you might recourse to a expression using set theoretical operations if it is not clear. Check Kechris' book for use cases.

Comment: Thanks. However here, we're adding a universal quantifier over a countable set. So isn't it true the complexity stays the same?

Comment: In $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists A\in F \forall n\in A |y_n - x_0| < \varepsilon$, indeed, the outermost universal quantifier _may be replaced_ by one over a countable set and then the complexity is the same as that of $\exists A\in F \forall n\in A |y_n - x_0| < \varepsilon$